# Difference between Array adapter and Cursor Adapter in Android

Tags: android

What is the difference between Array adapter and Cursor Adapter in Android?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Array Adapter : An adapter that takes an array of items and uses this array to build your list.

CursorAdapter : It takes a cursor which u receive as a result of a query to a sqlite database or a content resolver. You pass this cursor to the adapter and the list is created based upon the data present in the cursor.

Comment: for array adapter we have to pass the data from code??? while in cursor adapter data comes from database??? isn't???

Comment: You could say that. You could generate your data in an Array list in your code, for eg, an array of strings specifying the country names. You can then pass it to an array adapter to make a list of countries. In case of cursors, you get a cursor as a return data when you query the database or a content resolver (u need to read up on this)

Comment: @Shane  You can generate an ArrayAdapter from a db query as well.

Comment: Can anyone help me out?I have a onClickListener for the buttons in my listViews,i populate all the values for my 5 textviews and it works great.now what i want is when i click the button,1 textview should display how many times the button was clicked.i tryed many ways button the values are not getting refreshed.i added onclicklistener to my adapter class.

Answer (score 4):

Array Adapter
A concrete BaseAdapter that is backed by an array of arbitrary objects. You can add lists or arrays of custom objects

Cursor Adapter
Adapter that exposes data from a Cursor. The Cursor must include a column named "_id" or this class will not work.

Comment: Hi i am very new to android , I want to create database in SQLite for android application.. The data from database will be displayed in listview (image, name) using cursor adapter... what is the best way to do this. Should i have the holder class too to hold views created for custom list... 

Can you guide me in this with example... Step by step explanation is appreciated..

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: +1 for The Cursor must include a column named "_id" or this class will not work.

Comment: @Shane  You can use the Holder Pattern to make your ListView more efficient.  However, it is not a requirement that is dependent upon CursorAdapter exclusively.

Answer (score 1):

Array Adapter is for Array of Strings or data.. Cursor Adapter is used when you have Data in a Cursor.. e.g when you get data from database..

Comment: for array adapter we have to pass the data from code??? while in cursor adapter data comes from database??? isn't???

Comment: @Shane .. well yes.. something like that... Not only Database. anything that returns data in cursor..